# Error when installing 'react-navigation/stack' (Expo)

Tags: react-native, installation, expo, react-navigation-stack

I am following a full-stack RN tutorial and apparently need to install @react-navigation/stack.

I've already tried running `npm install` followed by `npm install --save react-navigation` and then trying to install the wanted package again to no avail.

I find this error (which I cannot understand) weird because I was able to run `npm install react-navigation/native` just a few minutes ago.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Oh! And I am using Expo.

[image]

Comment: What's the error ? Can you please add what's the error you are getting ?

Comment: Completely forgot to add that, thanks and sorry!

Comment: it looks like you are using some libraries that aren't compatible with npm 7 and are causing issues when installing this library. you should use npm 6 or run `npm install` with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag. in particular, `react-native-iphone-x-helper` is causing this issue

Comment: how do I lower my npm version to 6? Do I have to install 6 and then change the version somehow maybe with environmental variables or something?